# validate form with dynamic field using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, validation

i'm using [Jquery validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) to validate a form.

I fill my form dynamically using php.. for example:

```
<form name="my_form" id="my_form">
   <label for="static_field_1">Insert static field 1</label>
   <input type="text" name="static_field_1" id="static_field_1"/>
   <label for="static_field_2">Insert static field 2</label>
   <input type="text" name="static_field_2" id="static_field_2" />

   <?php
      $no_dynamic_field = count($dynamic_fields_array);
      if($no_dynamic_field>0){
         for($i=0;$i<$no_dynamic_field;$i++){
   ?>
         <label for="dynamic_field_<?php echo $i;?>">Insert field <?php echo $dynamic_fields_array[$i];?></label> 
         <input type="text" name="dynamic_field_<?php echo $i;?>" id="dynamic_field_<?php echo $i;?>" />
   <?php
         }
      }
   ?>
</form>
```

I have to validate this form.. so for static field there is no problem:

```
$('#my_form').validate({
   rules: {
      static_field_1:"required",
      static_field_2:"required"
   },
   messages:{
      static_field_1:"Static field 1 required!",
      static_field_2:"Static field 2 required!",
   }
});
```

but how can i loop through dynamic field to validate them?

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#my_form').validate();
});
```

and put `class='required'` on every input.So your code will be:

```
<form name="my_form" id="my_form">
   <label for="static_field_1">Insert static field 1</label>
   <input type="text" name="static_field_1" id="static_field_1" class='required'/>
   <label for="static_field_2">Insert static field 2</label>
   <input type="text" name="static_field_2" id="static_field_2" class='required'/>

   <?php if(count($dynamic_fields_array)>0)
      for($i=0;$i<count($dynamic_fields_array);$i++){
   ?>
      <label for="dynamic_field_<?php echo $i;?>">Insert field <?php echo $dynamic_fields_array[$i];?></label> 
      <input type="text" name="dynamic_field_<?php echo $i;?>" id="dynamic_field_<?php echo $i;?>" class='required'/>
   <?php
      }
   ?>
   <?php }?>
</form>
```

Comment: If the message is not specified, by default the message is: "This field is required.",

Comment: If you want to change the error message for all the required fields you can do this: `$.extend($.validator.messages, { required: "Required custom message" });`  Or do you want to make a custom message for each input field?

Comment: i prefer custom message for all fields